# An Accountant Seeks the Help of a Mathematician

Tags: logical-deduction, number-theory

The accountant complaints to the mathematician:

> “I lent money to five other faculty members and still haven’t been paid back. You are one of them; the other four owe me 12 dollars altogether, but I don’t remember how much each person owes me separately.”
>
> “Are the debts in whole dollars?”
>
> “Yes. I do remember that the four other debts multiplied together equals your debt. Do you remember how much you owe me?”
>
> “Yes, but I still haven’t figured out how much each of the other four owe you.”
>
> “Wait! The statistician is the one who owes the least.”
>
> “That does it. Now I know the amount of each debt.”

What are the debts and how did the mathematician determine them?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The mathematician owes

> 48 dollars

and the other faculty members owe

> 4, 4, 3 and 1 dollar.

Explanation:

> We know the total debt of the other four faculty members is 12, so we're looking for [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of 12 in four parts.  Let's list them and compute the product (which would be the mathematician's debt):

Table:

> `9 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 12 -->  9`
>  `8 + 2 + 1 + 1 = 12 --> 16`
>  `7 + 3 + 1 + 1 = 12 --> 21`
>  `7 + 2 + 2 + 1 = 12 --> 28`
>  `6 + 4 + 1 + 1 = 12 --> 24`
>  `6 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 12 --> 36`
>  `6 + 2 + 2 + 2 = 12 --> 48`
>  `5 + 5 + 1 + 1 = 12 --> 25`
>  `5 + 4 + 2 + 1 = 12 --> 40`
>  `5 + 3 + 3 + 1 = 12 --> 45`
>  `5 + 3 + 2 + 2 = 12 --> 60`
>  `4 + 4 + 3 + 1 = 12 --> 48`
>  `4 + 4 + 2 + 2 = 12 --> 64`
>  `4 + 3 + 3 + 2 = 12 --> 72`
>  `3 + 3 + 3 + 3 = 12 --> 81`
>  Now, the mathematician knows his own debt, so if he's unsure of the distribution of the others, there must be multiple partitions of 12 in four parts with a product equal to his debt. That's only the case for 48, which can be split as $6 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2$ and $4 \times 4 \times 3 \times 1$. Since there is a single least number among those (corresponding to the statistician's debt), it must be the second option.

Comment: Your explanation reminds me of the famous Clue scene: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O5ROhf5Soqs

Answer (score 5):

The mathematician owes

> \$48

Because

> nothing is said that the individual debts are unique, only that the lowest one must be.
>  So any of the following distributions of debts by the four remaining are possible, and thus the following possibilities for what the mathematician owes:
>
>  1,2,2,7 → \$28
>  1,2,3,6 → \$36
>  1,2,4,5 → \$40
>  1,3,3,5 → \$45
>  1,3,4,4 → \$48

Now the mathematician says at first that

> the other totals are not known to them until the accountant mentions that the statistician owes the least, thus requiring there to *be* a distinct "least".  Prior to that discovery, ...
>
>  The mathematician can't owe \$45 because there is only one way to sum to 12 and multiply to 45.
>  The mathematician can't owe \$36 because there is only one way to sum to 12 and multiply to 36.
>  The mathematician can't owe \$28 because there is only one way to sum to 12 and multiply to 28.
>  The mathematician could owe \$48 because 2,2,2,6 is another valid solution that sums to 12 and multiplies to 48, but is ruled out when the discovery is made.

Comment: In the second part, I think you are missing the possibility 2,3,3,4